# Is decimal expansion uniquely ergodic?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let the transformation decimal expansion $f : [0; 1] \rightarrow [0; 1]$, given by
$f(x) = 10x − \lfloor 10x\rfloor$
and m the Lebesgue measure in $[0; 1]$.

we know that $m$ is invariant by $f$ and that $m$ is ergodic to $f$.

My question is if $f$ is uniquely ergodic, which is: only the Lebesgue measure is invariant by $f$ and ergodic. I've been trying to prove this fact but I could not. I tried to prove by observing the following: The temporal mean of $f$ is constant almost everywhere by the ergodicity and Birkhoff's theorem. To show that it is uniquely ergodic I need to show that this convergence is always. Here I got lost.

Any suggestion? or counterexample? I do not know if it really uniquely is ergodic.

Comment: You can rewrite the decimal expansion as an irrational rotation and then you can apply what is known about unique ergodicity of those...

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$.  So, $f$ has at least one ergodic invariant measure other than the Lebesgue measure.  There are many more.

Comment: I'm confused. You're looking at temporal means of $f$? Isn't $f$ the transformation here?

Comment: @mathworker21          it is because proving that a measure is uniquely ergodic is equivalent to proving that the temporal mean converges at any point. By ergodicity and Birkhoff's theorem we already have convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: @Blackbird 
But $f (0) = 0$ implies that in the existence of measures? The result I know says that f must be continuous in a compact metric space so that it has an invariant measure.

Comment: @RicardoFreire  I don't think you know what you are talking about.

Comment: @RicardoFreire The Dirac measure $\delta_0$ is invariant.